# Logo cloning on navbar scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have the following script:

```js
$(function() {
  var header = $(".header-nav");

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 50) {
      header.addClass("scrolled");
    }
    if (scroll > 50 && scroll < 60) {
      $(".header_logo img").clone().appendTo(".header-logo");
    }
    if (scroll <= 50) {
      header.removeClass("scrolled");
    }
  });

});
```

It's supposed to make the `navbar` fixed on scroll and clone the website logo to the `navba`r on a `.header-logo` empty `div`

But it doesn't work as expected. The logo is mass duplicated or don't appear until a top scrolling.

Is there a way to make it work as: When I scroll, the logo is cloned one time on the `navbar` then disappear if you go back to top page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone `img` outside the condition, then append or remove based on your `if` condition. You need to set a `class` to detect cloned `img` for removing.

```js
$(function() {
  var header = $(".header-nav");
$el = $(".header-logo img").clone().addClass('cloned');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 50) {
      header.addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
      header.removeClass("scrolled");
    }
    
    if (scroll > 50) {
      $el.appendTo(".header-logo");
    } else {
      $('.cloned').remove();
    }

  });

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  /* fake height! */
}

header.header-nav.scrolled {
    position: fixed;
}

.header-nav {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.scrolled {
  background: red;
}

.header-logo img {
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header-nav">
  <div class="header-logo">
    <img src="https://i.graphicmama.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/02145410/logo-design-trends-2020-colorful-gradient-logos-example-1.gif" />
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: @Jesse Here it work fine, so if in your project not work, I can say there is another problem !

Comment: Ok I've found why. There was an error on header_logo img name in ur code.

By the way it still don't work, logo appears only when I scroll to the top page.

Comment: And it still mass duplicates if I scroll top several times.

Comment: By the way, I want the logo to stay here until a scroll to the top page. With your code, it diseapear to 100.

Comment: @Jesse Glad to help, please check answer as accepted ;)

Comment: Is there a way to make it appear when refreshing page at the middle for example?

Comment: @Jesse yeah of course. but I think you need to make a new question, this topic is over already.